# Kubernetes Application with multiple Resources single YAML

Tags: docker, kubernetes

currently i used docker-compose to arrange my application that consists of 3 dockerimages - a postgresql database and 2 wildfly application servers (Frontend-ui, backend).

My **docker-compose.yml** looks like this:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  my-webgui-service:
    image: test/mywebgui
    ports:
    - "18081:8080"
    links:
    - my-app-service
  my-app-service:
    image: test/myapp
    ports:
    - "18080:8080"
    - "29990:9990"
    links:
    - db-service
  db-service:
    image: test/postgres
    ports:
    - "15432:5432
```

Now, i would like to implement the same thing via kubernetes.

Is it possible to arrange this in a single yaml-File, that contains the configuration for service, deployment and pods?
I thought that it is easier to manage automated deployments when not having seperated yml-files.

Is this a best practise?

Best regards, Shane

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes it's possible, simply separate the different resources such as deployments, services, etc. with `---`. Concerning if it's a good practice or not: a matter of taste, rather. If you have all in one file it's more self-contained but for `kubectl apply -f` it doesn't really matter since it operates on directories as well.

Comment: @Shannon please consider accepting it as the answer so that others after you also recognize it as such …

Comment: How "kubectl apply -f " will know that which "kind" from the ymal file needs to be executed? I mean does ymal file with multiple kinds executes sequentially or it is executed based on a specific argument passed while running "kubectl apply -f" command. Thanks

Comment: @PrashantPathak your ask is entirely unrelated to this one here so, following good practices, you would create a new question. However, to address it: `apply` uses a three-way merge patch, best explained in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CW3ZuQy_YZw