# Substitute environment variable in all files when kubectl apply-ing

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl, envsubst

Let's say we have a number of Kubernetes configuration files in a folder `kubernetes` and we want to apply them all:

```
kubectl apply -f kubernetes -n MyNamespace
```

Some of these files contain environment variables which need to be substituted first (no [templating](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23896) in Kubernetes). For instance, several of the deployment yamls contain something like:

```
image: myregistry.com/myrepo:$TAG
```

For a single yaml file, this can be [done](https://serverfault.com/questions/791715/using-environment-variables-in-kubernetes-deployment-spec) e.g. by using envsubst like this:

```
envsubst < deploy.yml | kubectl apply -f -
```

What's the best way to do these substitutions for all the yaml files?

(Looping over the files in the folder and calling `envsubst` as above is one option, but I suspect that it would be preferrable to pass the entire folder to `kubectl` and not individual files)

Comment: Would either Kustomize or Helm fit your needs here?  Kustomize can directly set the image tag; Helm has a more general templating engine but setting image tags is a very common use for it.

Comment: Yes, both would solve the problem as well. In my particular case, there's only a single variable substitution, so I'm leaning towards a lightweight solution vs adding another tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
for f in *.yaml; do envsubst < $f | kubectl apply -f -; done
```

Comment: This is the better answer, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can let `envsubst` read the content of multiple files from standard input as if it were reading one file `< deploy.yaml` either using process substitution `<(..)` feature of `bash` or using plain ol' `cat`

```sh
envsubst < <(cat *.yaml) | kubectl apply -f -
```

or

```sh
cat *.yaml | envsubst - | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Thanks! This will make it look like one large configuration file to kubectl instead of several ones, right? Is there any downside to that?

Comment: @Max: It doesn't matter to `kubectl`, all it needs is a valid YAML to render. If you are worried about all the files being processed, name your files to suit the glob expressions, e.g. for deploy charts alone i.e. `deploy*.yaml`

Comment: ok great! No, I was just wondering if kubectl behaves differently if it gets separate files, e.g. processes them in parallel or does some other kind of optimization.

Comment: What really happens is, by the time, `kubectl` sees the input, it does not even know which files it came from, except its a content over its standard input i.e. `-`l, it doesn't really care

Comment: I spoke too soon- this actually doesn't quite work. Since kubectl considers the input a single file with multiple resources, there has to be a `---` separator between them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52255987.

Comment: Thanks to this thread, I've found a way to pass system env to Kustomize with envsubst: Just run `envsubst < <(kubectl kustomize overlays/staging) | kubectl apply -f -`

Comment: The 0.21 version of `envsubst` (current at the time of this writing) doesn't recognize the minus (`-`) as standard input, so the second form of this solution doesn't work with that version. The following would work instead: `cat *.yaml | envsubst | kubectl apply -f -`