# Kubernetes - Using system environment variables in ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes

I have some secrets etc. stored in system environment variables which I want to reference in my ConfigMap in kubernetes manifests. For example: I have this ${GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN} variable stored as environment variables and I want to reference it in my configMap as follows so I don't have to hardcode these tokens in the configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
  namespace: my-namespace
data:
  gitAccessToken: ${GIT_ACESS_TOKEN}
```

Is there a way to reference the System's Environment Variables in k8s manifests? Is kustomize or helm can help here? or any opensource controllers available for this?

I have tried deploying the above manifest to manifest but it is taking the ${GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN} as literal value and replacing this variable from my OS's environment.

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't have access to system environment variables. If you want to expose credentials in your Kubernetes environment, create a Secret and then use the `envFrom` or `valueFrom` directives in your Pod manifests.

Comment: Little bit more context here... I have environment variables in my manifest YAMLs.
And when i run `kubectl apply -f myconfig.yaml`, that environment variable reference must be replaced with actual value from the shell wherever the kubectl command is running. (and same behavior when using flux/kustomize etc.)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for. The Kubernetes documentation is pretty comprehensive on how to use Secrets and how to expose those values as environment variables (or as files in your pod filesystem). Are there docs you've read that don't make sense? Update your question with that information and we'll try to help out.

Comment: There is a devops exchange for k8s questions that aren't about programming.  https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe a templating tool like [Helm](https://helm.sh) will meet your needs?

Comment: Also see perhaps [Substitute environment variable in all files when kubectl apply-ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65705619/substitute-environment-variable-in-all-files-when-kubectl-apply-ing).

Comment: Thanks all for taking time to answer... the `envsubst` option looks good with manual execution of kubectl. I have environment with flux/kustomize too where manifests will be pulled from Git Repo and deployed. Is there a way for kustomization to support such environment variables?